# Avoiding custom events in Polymer

Tags: polymer, web-component

I was drawn to the idea of a "VanillaJS" approach mentioned by http://customelements.io/ for https://github.com/webcomponents/element-boilerplate . This drew me to http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/custom-elements.html (since I would like to do everything I can in JavaScript rather than use `<link/>` to do imports).

However, it seems that, contrary to the spirit of VanillaJS and polyfills, they seem to require their own custom "WebComponentsReady" event. (To me a polyfill is something which completely follows a standard or proposed standard, and lets you merely remove a script tag or load when it is fully supported and not need to change any other code.)

(Mozilla's x-tag (which is also not clear on whether it can be used purely as a polyfill or whether one requires the xtag global) uses a "DOMComponentsLoaded" event which I am not clear is standard.)

Neither event is mentioned at http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/

Any way to work with these to use a standard event or avoid these otherwise without polling?

**UPDATE**

I see from http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2013JulSep/0697.html that the "WebComponentsReady" event was discussed as being a candidate for specification but had not (at least at that time) been added, so I guess this event may be the safest bet since Mozilla's x-tag does [use it internally](https://github.com/x-tag/core/blob/d78bfde1dcfa58294528e6c782dbd1ec348fa1fc/src/core.js#L1100) immediately before firing its own "DOMComponentsLoaded" event and it was at least discussed as a possible candidate for standardization. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither event is part of the standards. Both Polymer's `WebComponentsReady` and x-tag's `DOMComponentsLoaded` are fired for convenience. This is one of those things you'd have to do yourself without a sugaring library. I suspect x-tag's fires hooks into the `WebComponentsReady` event because it uses the same set of polyfills as Polymer.

BTW, one reason to use an HTML Import (`<link rel="import">) to load components is that you get a`load` event. That could be one signal the component is ready.

Comment: I imagine I should be able to dynamically load a `<link/>` then, eh? I just hate dealing with any static HTML as it is not adequately modular...

Comment: Yep. You can dynamically create and load an import